# How to find the Probability density function here?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A ray of light is sent in a random direction towards the x-axis from a station Q(0,1) on the y-axis and the ray meets the x-axis at a point P. Find Probability density function of the abscissa of P.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Written the equation of line as y = mx+c and then passed it through (0,1) to get value of c= 1. then integrated mx+1 from 0 to x . Now how to proceed ahead ?

Comment: The ray makes an angle $\theta$ from $Q$ to $P$. A natural range for $\theta \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

1) What is a good choice for the distribution of $\theta$ (e.g. what is meant by random direction?)
2) Can you come up with a relation between $\theta$ and the $x$-coordinate of $P$.
3) Once that is done, you may find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

In particular the section on transforming random variables.

Comment: I hate problems that give vague descriptions of some event and then expect the solver to come up with precise probabilities from it, forcing them to guess at the details the author didn't bother to include. Not your fault, but the author would get a "D" from me.

Comment: Well it is not asking precise probability rather it is asking to find the Probability density function.